# How do $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}^2$ have the same dimension over $\Bbb{Q}$ as vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{R}^2$ have the same dimension over $\Bbb{Q}$ as vector spaces?

Having the same dimension would imply that both have the same number of basis elements. How do I prove that they have the same number of basis elements? It is easy to see that both have an infinite number of basis elements though.

Comment: If you have an infinite set $V$, do you know that $V$ and $V^2$ has the same cardinality?

Comment: In general, if $X$ is an infinite set then $X\times\{1,2\}$ has the same cardinality as $X$. Be very careful about the term "number of," which is a misnomer.

Comment: @Arthur- How would you go about proving that?

Comment: @Arthur- Also, how does same cardinality imply same dimension?

Comment: @algebraically_speaking For infinite bases, wouldn't you agree that "same dimension" should mean "have bases of the same cardinality"?

Comment: @rschwieb- Yes, but here, assuming Arthur's statement, we can say that the two vector spaces have the same cardinality. How does this imply that the cardinality of the bases (which may not be equal to the cardinality of the sets) should also be the same?

Comment: @algebraically_speaking the "infinite sets" that Arthur is referring to are the bases, not the vector spaces

Comment: Also, note that the existence of bases for these vector spaces requires the axiom of choice (or a weakened version thereof).